# Combine random array items into sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, sentence

What I'm trying to do is basically take the below code and make it work so that I can combine items from several arrays into one sentence.  So for instance, right now if I run this code it will give me random items from `myarray`, *i.e. `item1`, `2`, etc.*  But what I would like to do is create several arrays and have the result be a sentence which includes (in this order) random items *from `array1`, `array2`, `array3`, etc.*  Basically, a random sentence generator using arrays.  What differs between this and proposed duplicate item is that I already know how to randomize items within a single array, but would like to combine several array items into one sentence structure.  `(array1 item) + (array2 item) + (array3 item)`

```
 function GetValue()
{
var myarray= new Array("item1","item2","item3");
var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
}
```

```js
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array("item1","item2","item3");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="message" ></>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is the create 2 more arrays and do the same thing to get a random word then concatenate them together. Like this:

```js
function GetValue() {
  var myarray1 = new Array("item1", "item2", "item3");
  var myarray2 = new Array("item4", "item5", "item6");
  var myarray3 = new Array("item7", "item8", "item9");
  var random1 = myarray1[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray1.length)];
  var random2 = myarray2[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray2.length)];
  var random3 = myarray3[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray3.length)];
  var output = random1 + ' ' + random2 + ' ' + random3;

  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="message">
  </>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp):

```
var myarray= new Array("item1","item2","item3");
while(myarray.length>0){
    var random = myarray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length));
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += ' ' + random;
}
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/1tmqbyc5/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var fragments = [];
fragments.push(["I","You","We","He","She"]);
fragments.push(["called","left","saw","loved","hated"]);
fragments.push(["the","a","some","another"]);
fragments.push(["store","person","rabbit","dog"]);

function getSentence() {
    var sentence = '';
    for (var i=0; i<fragments.length; i++) {
        sentence += fragments[i][Math.floor(Math.random() * fragments[i].length)] + ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = (sentence.trim() + '.');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="getSentence();" />
<p id="message" ></>
```